# How to include external python modules with pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm new in python and trying to launch my pyspark project on spark on AWS EMR.
The project is disposed on AWS S3 and has several python files, like this:

```
/folder1
 - main.py
/utils
 - utils1.py
 - utils2.py
```

I use the following command:

```
spark-submit --py-files s3://bucket/utils s3://bucket/folder1/main.py
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/tmp/spark-1e38eb59-3ddd-4deb-8529-eace7465b6ce/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    from utils.utils1 import foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

What I have to fix in my command? I know that I can pack my project in zip file, but now I need to do it without packing, however I'll be grateful if you tell me both solutions.

**UPD:**

EMR cluster's controller log says, that launching command looks like this:

`hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-jars/command-runner.jar spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.1 --driver-memory 100G --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=100G --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.maxRetries=20 --conf spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode=dynamic --py-files s3://bucket/dir1/dir2/utils.zip --master yarn s3://bucket/dir1/dir2/dir3/main.py --args`

But now I have the following error:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/cluster-id/dir1/dir2/utils.zip does not exist`

What's wrong?

Comment: "Now I need to do it without packaging" ... why? `py-files` supports egg and zip files, not folders, AFAIK

Comment: Because we  just started the project and don't have CI yet. But if it's a bad practice in python, I'll put everything in zip file.

Comment: You don't need "CI". You could make a simple shell script that runs `zip` and `spark-submit` together

Comment: Also, note that EMR support should be able to provide you "best practices" for how to submit your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although not recommended (see the complete answer for a better option), but if you do not want to zip files. Instead of providing `utils` folder, you can provide individual utils-* files with py-files with comma-separated syntax before the actual file as

```
'Args': ['spark-submit',
                '--py-files',
                '{your_s3_path_here}/utils/utils1.py,{your_s3_path_here}/utils/utils1.py',
                'main.py']
        }
```

**Better to zip utils folder**

You can `zip` utils and include like this

To do so, make empty `__init__.py` file at root level in `utils` like utils/__init__.py )

From outside this directory, make a zip of it (for example `utils.zip`)

For submission, you can add this zip as

```
'Args': ['spark-submit',
                '--py-files',
                '{your_s3_path_here}/utils.zip',
                'main.py'
        }
```

Considering your have `__init__.py` , `utils1.py`, `utils2.py` in `utils.zip`

**Note:** You might also need to add this zip to sc with `sc.addPyFile("utils.zip")` before following imports

You can now use them as

```
from utils.utils1 import *
from utils.utils2 import *
```

Comment: What do I have to specify here: `sc.addPyFile("utils.zip")`? Should I specify full path on s3, for example `sc.addPyFile("/d1/d2/utils.zip")` or just a file name is enough?

Comment: You wont need full path, just utils.zip

Comment: I'm still getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-3P1Q1C80AK1FP/utils.zip does not exist

Comment: Did you submit utils via '--py-files' '{your_s3_path_here}/utils.zip' like shown in answer?

Comment: Do you have access to cluster launching script or bootstrap script?

Comment: I've answered in update

Comment: Hello, I cant see .zip in your spark submit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238031/discussion-between-vladimir-shadrin-and-a-b).